# How can I register a service as a scoped on Azure Function Isolated-Model?

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-functions

On Azure function, there are differences between in-process and isolated-model. Especially the perspective from the Dependency Injection.

As you can see in this reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection), Microsoft explains Azure Function dependency injection for the in-process model. And also, Microsoft says the dependency injection feature relies on regular ASP.NET Core dependency injection patterns for an Azure Function isolated model. You can see this explanation from the link that I shared.
In this case, I assume that if I register a service as scoped, the DI will create this service instance per function invocation request lifetime. But as I see it, it works like Transient registration. AddScoped is not working correctly. Here are the re-produce steps;

1 - Create an azure Function using.Net 6 Isolated Model.

2 - Add a service to the solution as like this;

```
 public class Service1
 {
    public Service1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service1 triggered");
    }
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
 }
```

3 - Add a very simple middleware that gets injected Service1 into the constructor. Like this;

```
public class TestMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    private readonly Service1 _service1;

    public TestMiddleware(Service1 service1)
    {
        service1 = service1;
        Console.WriteLine("TestMiddleware constructor");
    }

    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        await next(context);
    }
}
```

4 - Register the service into the Dependency Injection Container and use middleware using Program.cs. like this;

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((builder, services) =>
    {
        services.AddScoped<Service1>();
    })
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(opt =>
    {
        opt.UseMiddleware<TestMiddleware>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

5- Add a simple function that gets registered Service1 into its constructor. Like this;

```
public class TestFunction
{
    private readonly Service1 _service1;

    public TestFunction(Service1 service1)
    {
        _service1 = service1;
    }

    [Function("TestFunc")]
    public async Task<string> TestFunc(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "TestFunction/TestFunc")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        _service1.DoSomething();
        return "Ok";
    }
}
```

And then, observe that Service1 going to create two times for a request, and you will see the "Service1 triggered" in the console two times.

Can someone explain, Service1 getting created by DI for a request two times? It should use the first instance since it is still in the same invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#service-lifetimes) from the ASP.NET Dependency Injection docs, when working with scoped dependencies and middleware, you need to inject into the `Invoke` method instead of the constructor or use [factory-based middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/extensibility?view=aspnetcore-7.0) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same instance of the scoped service in both the middleware and Function by using the `IServiceProvider` in `context.InstanceServices`.

```cs
public class TestMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public TestMiddleware()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestMiddleware constructor");
    }

    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var service1 = context.InstanceServices.GetRequiredService<Service1>();
        await next(context);
    }
}
```